# Connected App showing in App Menu

Tags: apex, metadata-api, connected-apps, canvas

While creating a connected app, it is automatically added to the App Menu. Is there a way to prevent a connected app being added automatically to App Menu?

FYI: I am creating connected app via Metadata API. But if I create another connected app manually, still it is being added to App Menu.

Comment: did you try removing the start URL? when you are saying app menu you are meaning app launcher right?

Comment: Thanks a lot @RedDevil, removing the start URL removes the connected app from App Menu and App Launcher.

Comment: Mark this as solution as it  may help others.No pressure or force to do it though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the **startURL** from the connected App and it wont show up in your App Menu